# SVG in JavaScript not rendering correctly

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-animate, svg-animate

I am adding dots to a map that correspond to tweets across the world. When a tweet is added, it will be represented by a red dot.

Over the next 30 seconds (same interval as the Tweet polling delay), the dots will fade slowly to black to show that they are old.

The following code does just that, but after the first poll, subsequent polls change the color of all dots on the map, both new and old, to red. Furthermore, the fading animation only happens when the first set of points are mapped.

Any ideas why?

[**Here's the map in action. View in a modern browser.**](http://jonathonmoore.com/mkt/index2.php)

```
function addCircle(coordinates, tipText, r) {
    tweetNumber++;

    // Max number of dots on a map at any given time
    if (tweetNumber == 200) {
        tweetNumber = 0;
    }

    // Removes expired circles 
    $('#' + tweetNumber).remove();

    var rad;
    //determine if radius size needs to be bumped
    if (arguments.length == 3) {
        rad = r;
    } else {
        rad = 3;
    }

    // Add radar-style ping effect
    map.append('svg:circle')
        .style("stroke", "rgba(255,49,49,.7)")
        .style("fill", "rgba(0,0,0,0)")
        .attr("cx", coordinates[0])
        .attr("cy", coordinates[1])
        .attr("r", 3)
        .transition()
        .delay(0)
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("r", 30)
        .style("stroke", "rgba(255,49,49,0.0001)").transition().duration(2000).remove();

    // Add circles representing tweets
    map.append('svg:circle').attr("class", "tweetCircles")
        .attr("id", tweetNumber)
        .style("fill", "rgba(240,49,49,1)")
        .attr("cx", coordinates[0])
        .attr("cy", coordinates[1])
        .attr("r", rad)
            .append("svg:animate") // Fade effect (only works 1st time)
                .attr("attributeName", "fill")
                .attr("from", "rgba(255,0,0,1)")
                .attr("to", "rgba(0,0,0,1)")
                .attr("dur", "30s");

    // Adds a tooltip to each dot to read the tweets
    addTipsy(tipText, tweetNumber);
}
```

Comment: As a matter of style, I'd be inclined to suggest moving the dot operator in your chained JS to the end of each line rather than at the start of the next. This is because JS engines add an [implicit semicolon](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2011/04/javascript-gotcha-implicit-semi-colon-insertion/) if a line _could_ end immediately without a semi-colon terminator. Putting the dot on the end makes it obvious to the engine that there's more code to come!

Comment: Interesting thought. I'll make this change! EDIT: This didn't seem to work...unless I missed a dot somewhere :/

Comment: Didn't work as in _stopped working completely_, or just as in _the same as before_? Also, run your code through JSLint to see if there are any other surprises `:)`

Comment: Stopped completely. I'll check out JSLint.

Comment: Ah, so that might mean stuff wasn't getting executed before, so potentially you are now further on. The next step is to remove a bunch of those lines until it starts working, and see which one is at fault. Keep an eye on your console, of course, in case new errors have now started appearing.

Comment: No known JavaScript parser would insert a semicolon, nor would the spec allow it, if the first character on the next line was a dot. If this were the case, hundreds of millions of lines of JS code (including most d3 code) would stop working.